# log4j Log Indexing using Solr

Tags: search, indexing, lucene, solr, log4j

We are finding it very hard to monitor the logs spread over a cluster of four managed servers. So, I am trying to build a simple log4j appender which uses solrj api to store the logs in the solr server. The idea is to use leverage REST of solr to build a better GUI which could help us

1. search the logs and the display the previous and the next 50 lines or so and
2. tail the logs

Being awful on front ends, I am trying to cookup something with GWT (a prototype version). I am planning to host the project on googlecode under ASL.

Greatly appreciate if you could throw some insights on

1. Whether it makes sense to create a project like this ?
2. Is using Solr for this an overkill?
3. Any suggestions on web framework/tool which will help me build a tab-based front end for tailing.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea for a project. There's already one that logs to file and indexes with lucene, perhaps you can setup a gui that hooks into that index? Failing that, i'd defo think about it as two modules 1. the appender and 2. the ui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [logstash](http://logstash.net/) (for shipping and filtering logs) +  [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) (for indexing and storage) + [kibana](http://kibana.org/)  (for a pretty GUI).

Comment: This is great Stuff. Kibana looks very promising. Almost like splunk

Answer (score 2):

The loggly folks have also built [logstash](http://logstash.net/), which can be backed by quite a few things, including lucene via elastic search. It can forward to graylog also.

Answer (score 0):

Totally doable thing.  Many folks have done the roll your own.  A couple of useful links..   there is an online service, www.loggly.com that does this.  They are actually based on Solr as the core storage engine!  Obviously they have built a proprietary interface.

Another option is http://www.graylog2.org/.  It is opensource.  Not backed by Solr, but still very cool!

Comment: Thanks Eric. The links are really helpful.